# Magento 2.4: Product List widget not rendering

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am using Magento 2.4.4, I have tried to add Product List widget on my home page, but it appears like a string on frontend
``` {{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" title="Featured Products" show_pager="0" products_count="5" template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`category_ids`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`__FEATURED_PRODUCTS_CATEGORY_ID__`^]^]"}} ```

Comment: Depends on where your widget comes from, have you placed it programmatically or inside the wysiwyg editor?

Comment: Product List widget comes from vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/Block/Product/ProductsList.php. I added it with page builder on home page.

Product List looks like this: 

` <?php


namespace Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product;

use ...;

class ProductsList extends AbstractProduct implements BlockInterface, IdentityInterface
{
}`

Answer (score 0):

Have tried to render widget in Magento 2.4.4 and it seems working fine without any issue. Only 1 thing noticed what's purpose of category ids filter with == sign and passed value in variable.  Please try below if that works for you as well.

{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" title="testing" show_pager="1" products_per_page="5" products_count="10" template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`category_ids`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`20, 21`^]^]" page_var_name="poxpzg"}}

Answer (score 0):

1. Dont past this code in the text editor but do it in the html editor. Then the string on your front page will be gone.
2. To get results, change the operator == to ()